# Not showing error messages when I validate the form in Spring MVC

Tags: java, forms, validation, spring-mvc

I have a problem when i validate the form. the form takes into account validation, but the error messages are not displayed.

Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveUser", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String addUtilisateur(@Valid user util, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model)throws Exception{   
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        model.addAttribute("user", new user()); 
        return "login";
    }
        metier.ajoutUser(util);
    return "login";
}
```

User.java :

```
@Entity
public class user implements Serializable{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long idUser;
@Column(unique=true)
@NotEmpty
private String login;
@NotEmpty
private String password;
private String action;
public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}
public void setLogin(String login) {
    this.login = login;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public Long getIdUser() {
    return idUser;
}
public void setIdUser(Long idUser) {
    this.idUser = idUser;
}

public String getAction() {
    return action;
}
public void setAction(String action) {
    this.action = action;
}
public user() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public user(String login, String password) {
    super();
    this.login = login;
    this.password = password;
}
```

login.jsp :

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="f"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<f:form modelAttribute="user" action="saveUser" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Login</td>
<td><f:input path="login"/>
<f:errors path="login" cssClass="errors"></f:errors> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Pass word</td>
<td><f:input type="password" path="password"/>
<f:errors path="password" cssClass="errors"></f:errors> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="Login"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</f:form>
</body>
</html>
```

there's there a solution for that error messages are displayed well ??

Comment: piece of advice, begin Java Class names with a UpperCase letter, good practice to do so

Comment: yes you're right, it's just an example that I made my next project to test the error

Comment: one question, probably nothing to do with the issue, but how do you actually submit the form? I just see a table with input boxes, but no submit button for example

Comment: I already made a submit button

Comment: ok can you try these 2 steps: (1) put the button within the form tags, don't think it makes a difference to your issue but just makes sense to have it within the form tags (2) in the jsp change action="saveUser" to action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/saveUser"

Comment: I had the same problem with this solution

Comment: What is the error you are expecting to see btw?

Comment: when you enter valid values, does the form actually save the user? because it may be that the page is submitting but not actually processing the form

Comment: Yes, when i enter valid values, the form save the user